# Accessing global variables from inside a module

Tags: python

I wrote some python code to control a number of USB (electrical relays and temperature sensors) and RS232 (vacuum gauges) devices. From within this main script (e.g., `myscript.py`), I would like to import a module (e.g., `exp_protocols.py`) where I define different experimental protocols, i.e. a series of instructions to open or close relays, read temperature and pressure values, with some simple flow control thrown in (e.g. "wait until temperature exceeds 200 degrees C").

My initial attempt looked like this:

```
switch_A = Relay('A')
switch_B = Relay('B')
gauge_1 = Gauge('1')

global switch_A
global switch_B
global gauge_1

from exp_protocols import my_protocol
my_protocol()
```

with `exp_protocols.py` looking like this:

```
def my_protocol():
    print 'Pressure is %.3f mbar.' % gauge_1.value
    switch_A.close()
    switch_B.open()
```

This outputs a global variable error, because `exp_protocols.my_protocol` cannot access the objects defined in `myscript.py`.

It seems, from reading the answers to earlier questions here, that I could (should?) create all my `Relay` and `Gauge` variable in another module, e.g., `myconfig.py`, and then `import myconfig` both in `myscript.py` and `exp_protocols`? But if I do that, won't my `Relay` and `Gauge` objects be created twice (thus trying to open serial ports already active, etc.)?

What would be the best (most Pythonic) way to achieve this kind of inter-module communication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not pass `switch_A`, `switch_B` and `gauge_1` as function parameters to `my_protocol`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how many times you `import myconfig`, python only imports the module once. After the first import, future import statements just grab another reference to the module.

Globals should only be used if these are static bits of data. Your function would be more generic if it took the variables as parameters:

```
def my_protocol(switch_A, switch_B, gauge_1):
    print 'Pressure is %.3f mbar.' % gauge_1.value
    switch_A.close()
    switch_B.open()
```

modules could use it with many combinations of data. Suppose you have blocks of switches in a list (and I'm just making this up because I have no idea how you configure your data...), you could process them all with the same function:

```
import exp_protocols

switch_blocks = [
    [Relay('1-A'), Relay('1-B'), Gauge('1-1')],
    [Relay('2-A'), Relay('2-B'), Gauge('2-1')],
]

for switch1, switch2, gauge in switch_blocks:    
    exp_protocols.my_protocol(switch1, switch2, gauge)
```